# Formdata With Axios and ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, multipartform-data

I want to send a file from RN Client to my server via Axios.
I set the header to

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
```

what is the right structure for a form data? when I use the below structure I got network error ,[image]

the uri is

`content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F68/ORIGINAL/NONE/1971791263`

I also used the `formData.append(name, value, filename);` with this structure the uri is not sent as a file it will be sent as a string!

**How can I solve this?** thank you all

Comment: Are you replacing your headers when posting ? you should have the multipart form data in your header

Comment: I pass it into headers also no difference in result

Comment: Any possibility of sharing your whole code? so that its easy to understand

Comment: I sent you a msg on fb @GuruparanGiritharan thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Please pass a value with the below formate, refer [source reference](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app-4cca03ded855)

```
  const data = new FormData();

  data.append("photo", {
    name: photo.fileName,
    type: photo.type,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android" ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace("file://", "")
  });
```